# Redux with react-navigation (reactnavigation.org)

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm working on an example project integrating https://reactnavigation.org/ with Redux.

I have all the navigation stuff working and have set up an action inside my dashboard to get data from an API on fetch button click.
https://github.com/starchand/SampleNavigation/blob/master/app/containers/dashboard/views/Dashboard.js

This is working - I am getting the data, however I am also getting an random action being executed before:

[image]

Any ideas whats causing the first action?

Full repo: https://github.com/starchand/SampleNavigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by taking a quick look at your code, it seems to me the order of middleware you are applying to the store should be the reversed.

When you are doing `this.props.fetchQuestions(1);` inside your `Dashboard` component,  you are dispatching a function (or thunk) instead of a plain object. Since `redux-logger` is the first middleware in the chain, it's logging the function itself, with obviously `undefined` action type. Reverting the order of middlewares should fix the problem.

Inside https://github.com/starchand/SampleNavigation/blob/master/app/store.js#L16 try:

```
 return applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger())
```